# How I can integrate this js in drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

this wind the following plugin to force downloads

[jquery.fileDownload.js](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)

I want to integrate drupal 7

and put in theme.info jquery.fileDownload.js

dwnload-force.js besides containing the following code:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.MyfunctionTheme = {
attach: function(context, settings) {
$(document).on("click", "b.fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience", function () {
$.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
preparingMessageHtml: "Se esta preparando su descarga, por favor espere un momento...",
failMessageHtml: "Hubo un problema al generar su descarga, porfavor intente de nuevo."
});
return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
});
}}
})( jQuery );
```

firebug shows me the following:

```
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function  

$(document).on("click", "b.fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience", function () {
```

than you

Comment: Update you version of jquery to 1.7+

Comment: Musa thanks now i get the following error:
TypeError: $(...).html(...).dialog is not a function
[Detener en este error]  

...ngDialog = $("<div>").html(settings.preparingMessageHtml).dialog(settings.dialog...